# Prevent background events trigger when clicking on overlay div

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a `Backbone` view and I have attached some events to it:

```
var View1 = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function() {
      // ...
  },

   events: {
      "touchend .elem": "callback",
       // ...
    }

  render: function() {
      // ...
  }

});
```

Now, when I render `View1` another view (`View2`) is rendered first and this has a `div` that overlays the `View1` elements.
That `div` has these `CSS` properties:

```
.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22) !important;
    z-index: 500;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

`View2` disappears after some seconds.
The problem is that if I click on the overlay before it disappears, the events under the overlay are triggered and so, in my example, the `callback` function would be called.

I tried to attach a fake event to `View2` by doing this:

```
var View2 = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function() {
      // ...
  },

  events: {
      // ...
      "touchend .overlay":   "overlayCallback"
  },

  overlayCallback: function( event ) {
      if ( event ) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopImmediatePropagation();
          event.stopPropagation();
      }
      return false;
  },

  render: function() {
      // ...
  }

});
```

but it does not solve my problem.

How can I prevent `View1` from triggering the events when user clicks on `View2` overlay `div`?

Thanks

Comment: We have no idea about the structure of your DOM. You should provide a [mcve]

Comment: @TJ, I thought it was not necessary because I just need a way to disable touch events of all divs under the overlay div. Thanks

Comment: That totally depends on what you mean by *under*. it could be *under*  for the eyes, just visually. We need to know the relationship of these elements in DOM, and the entire CSS that goes on. In short a [mcve]

Comment: @Frank did you work it out yet?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming View1 calls View2, You could do it like:

1. Add your View1 as a parameter to View2s initialize-method
2. then, use `undelegateEvents` - method as stated in the
   backbonejs-[docs](http://backbonejs.org/) in your initialize-method of view2 to disable
   the events of view1 temporarily.
3. on close of View2, re-delegate
   your events using `delegateEvents` - method in View1 or create a
   custom method in view1 and call it from view2's reference to view1.